# STM32 with CP2102N able to receive but unable to transmit

Tags: usb, stm32

I have a PCB that I have designed which uses an STM32 and CP2102N. I am able to receive data sent from my computer to the board when I plug it into my computer, but I am unable to send data from the board to my computer. I connected an oscilloscope to the USB data pins and confirmed that *something* is being sent over the wires. I also already made sure that the settings I am using in my serial terminal match those in the STM32CubeIDE project configuration. (shown below)

[image]
[image]

Also, my code for transmitting the data is:

```c
uint8_t test_msg[] = "H";
HAL_StatusTypeDef tx_status = HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, test_msg, sizeof(test_msg), 10);
```

I have also confirmed that tx_status is HAL_OK after attempting to transmit. What could cause this?

Comment: Seeing activity on the USB lines doesn't really tell you much. There's always activity there, even when nothing is being sent or received over your CP2102. Did you probe the TX line from your STM32's UART to the CP2102?

Comment: @brhans I did not, but I can give that a try. Did the code look correct?

Answer (score 1):

Was able to resolve the issue by going over all the connections with a soldering iron. Keeping this post up for anyone else that is as stuck as I was.